# sizeof my structure array are different... why?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double value1;
    int value2;
    int value3;
}dynArr;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    dynArr a1[SIZE];
    dynArr* a2[SIZE];
    printf("Size of a1 array: %d\n", sizeof(a1));
    printf("Size of a2 array: %d\n", sizeof(a2));
    return 0;
}
```

The first prints out 160.

The second prints out 40.

I figure 4 bytes per element and there are 10 elements for the 2nd one. But I can't figure out why the first one has 160.

Thanks.

Comment: You could print out `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(int)` and add them up.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the element size would be 4? Try printing out `sizeof(dynArr)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`a1` is an array of structs, `a2` is an array of pointer of structs.

---

`a1` is composed of `SIZE` (10) structs, laid out consecutively in memory.

```
----------- ----------- ------- ----------- -----------
| struct0 | | struct1 | | ... | | struct8 | | struct9 |
----------- ----------- ------- ----------- -----------
```

Its size is `SIZE * sizeof(dynArr)` = 10 * 16 = 160

**Why 16 bytes per struct?**

```
typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double value1; // sizeof(double) = 8
    int value2;    // sizeof(int)    = 4
    int value3;    // sizeof(int)    = 4
} dynArr;
```

Take the sum of those and you have 16 bytes. (May even be more than the sum of individual sizes depending on padding)

---

`a2` is composed of `SIZE` (10) pointers to structs, laid out consecutively in memory. Its size is `SIZE * sizeof(dynArr*)` = 10 * 4 = 40

**Why 4 bytes per pointer?**

That's the size of a pointer on most 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed on your platform, that

```
typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double value1;  /* 8 Bytes */
    int value2;     /* 4 bytes */
    int value3;     /* 4 Bytes */
}dynArr;
```

and that there are no padding bytes between the structure elements.

Then, the size of the struct would be 16 bytes, so 16 * 10 = 160

Answer (score 0):

`a1` is in your case a array of the structures. The structure itself has the size of 16 Bytes (double is 8 Byte, int is 4 Byte) and so you get the size of 160 byte.

`a2` is a array of pointers. The size of one pointer is 4 Bytes (due your 32-bit system) and so you get a total size of 40 bytes.

Keep at this point in mind that `a2` is not initializied. So it does not really contain your structes it just keeps some space were you can store pointers to your structure.